# I am trying to use the same css file for several JSP pages, but it's only working in one. Why?

Tags: html, css, jsp

My header JSP file is having the expected behavior. But the other two are not.

header.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<title>JSP food order app</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h2 class="header">This is my header</h2>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>

<% %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="order.jsp">
        <label>Pizza 1: </label><input type="number" name="pizza1"/>
        <label>Pizza 2: </label><input type="number" name="pizza2"/>
        <label>Burger: </label><input type="number" name="burger" />
        <label>Soda: </label><input type="number" name="soda" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

order.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
<title></title>
</head>
<body class="order-body">
<%
int numOfPizza1;
int numOfPizza2;
int numOfBurger;
int numOfSoda;
out.println("<h1 class='order-title'>order proceded</h1>");
%>


</body>
</html>
```

and my styles.css

```
@charset "ISO-8859-1";

header {
    background-color: #10107c;
    line-height: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.header {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0;
}

form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.order-body {
    background-color: blue;
}

.order-title {
    color: blue;
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. I have different classes for each element. I have linked them properly. It's even showing the link when I inspect my code on chrome. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem, you are putting a slash '/' in the index and header files after you write href= "style.css".

You are writing it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
```

You should write it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

Notice that I've removed the slash. The slash is causing the problem